# Missing code block language when using the Stack Exchange API

Tags: support, stack-exchange, stackexchange.com, api

I managed to search and get questions with HTML body with Stack Exchange API.

I am using the following request:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/advanced?filter=withbody&tagged=node.js&site=stackoverflow&page=1&pagesize=1
```

The `filter=withbody` allows me to get the HTML.

However the code block inside the HTML does not have a class or any attributes telling me what is the language.

How can I get it?

I cannot find anything in the documentation for [filters](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters), or by [searching](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search).

**Edit:**

Since the URL above is changing results, I make another example so it is easier to see.

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/7172784?filter=withbody&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow
```

And this is the link to the question:
[How do I POST JSON data with cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-do-i-post-json-data-with-curl)

As you can see the question is using 3 different languages, however the HTML I get is always `<pre><code>` only, without any class or attribute.

**Edit 2:**

Apparently that wasn't a good example. It seems a lot of people is just not defining the language in the code block.

I was checking the rendered HTML in the browser and I saw that each time the language was autodetected, therefore there was syntax highlighting. I thought it was the user defining it, I was wrong.

Now I have to found how to autodetect the code language.

Comment: The code block [in the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73541178/edit) doesn't have any language hints. It's just a plain code fence. `\`\`\``

Comment: In that case the highlighting is inferred from the tags used.

Comment: You're using the `filter` parameter incorrectly. You should go to the page for the endpoint you're using (e.g. [`/search/advanced`](//api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search)), then click on the '[edit]` to the right of "**default** filter" to open a popup showing the available objects and their properties. Select the ones you want and de-select the ones you don't. Click "save" in the popup when done. Other than "default", `filter` values are almost never human readable. To get the HTML body of questions and answers, a filter should look something like `!6VvPDzQ)xXOrL`.

Comment: @Luuklag there can be more than one language, as in the edit I am showing.

Comment: @nbl7 the question [still has no language hints](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7172784/edit). It's just code.

Comment: "*there can be more than one language, as in the edit I am showing.*" in that case the syntax highlighter uses r̶a̶n̶d̶o̶m̶ ̶ fun mode. It tries to *guess* what the correct language is. And then in return you're supposed to *guess* why in the world it decided that. It's not unusual to see a question tagged [javascript] and [html] to get, for example, Lisp highlighting.

Comment: @nbl7 there can only be more then one langauge used for highlighting if explicitly defined in the code blocks. Otherwise it is most likely just the default language hint being used. Makyen's answer explain is all in great detail.

Comment: @VLAZ I see what you mean. I was checking the HTML of the rendered page. Then how the render knows about the language and the syntax highlighting. Can you give me an example where there is code then? Thank you!

Comment: @Makyen I've tried to build a filter as you explained, however I couldn't find the filter "withbody" that I needed.

Comment: @nbl7 My earlier comment was wrong, in saying you're using `filter` incorrectly. I'm sorry about that. As the [filter documentation states](//api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) (which I should have reread) `withbody` is valid as "`default` plus the `*.body` fields". The other valid human-readable values are `default`, `none`, and `total`. The process I described above of going through and picking the values which you desire is the "typical" way that filters are created. Unfortunately, the SE API is a bit twitchy with respect to filters and some combinations don't perform quite as indicated.

Answer (score 9):

#### The HTML from the SE API has no indication of the syntax highlighting language, unless a highlighting language is explicitly specified in Markdown

The HTML which the SE API provides doesn't contain any indication of which syntax highlighting language should be used on `<pre><code>` blocks when the language to be used hasn't been explicitly defined in the Markdown. If there's no explicit specifier, then the highlighting language(s) used will be either the "default" set of languages or the highlighting language defined for the tags on the on question. If more than one tag has a defined highlighting language, then the default set is used.

If the syntax highlighting language has been explicitly defined for a `<pre><code>` block, then the `<pre>` will have a `class` attribute with a class of `prettyprint-override` and a class indicating the syntax highlighting language, such as `lang-js`.

#### HTML with an explicitly defined syntax highlighting language

With an explicitly defined syntax highlighting language of `lang-js`, the HTML will look like:

```
<pre class="lang-js prettyprint-override"><code>[code here]</code></pre>
```

#### HTML without an explicitly defined syntax highlighting language

Without an explicitly defined syntax highlighting language, the HTML will look like:

```
<pre><code>[code here]</code></pre>
```

#### Example HTML from the SE API

If you desire, you can get HTML which contains examples of all of the above from [the results on this page in the SE API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=18410&filter=!-)QWsboN0-4y&site=meta&run=true), which gets the body for [answer to: "What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/271271) That answer also has an explanation of how syntax highlighting works from the perspective of entering Markdown into Stack Exchange. It does not, however, show what the resulting HTML will be.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in [the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381626/missing-code-block-language-when-using-stackexchange-api#comment1272993_381626) [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381626/missing-code-block-language-when-using-stackexchange-api#comment1272994_381626), it's possible to have a code block without specifying the language, in which case the question tags are used to decide the language.

More details can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/152859).